# Call a Stored Procedure From a Stored Procedure and/or using COUNT

Tags: mysql

Ok, First off, I am not a mysql guru. Second, I did search, but saw nothing relevant related to mysql, and since my DB knowledge is limited, guessing syntactical differences between two different Database types just isn't in the cards.

I am trying to determine if a particular value already exists in a table before inserting a row. I've decided to go about this using two Stored procedures. The first:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `nExists` ( n VARCHAR(255) ) BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=n) as T;
END
```

And The Second:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `createUser` ( n VARCHAR(255) ) BEGIN
    IF (nExists(n) = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO Users...
    END IF;
END
```

So, as you can see, I'm attempting to call nExists from createUser. I get the error that no Function exists with the name nExists...because it's a stored procedure. I'm not clear on what the difference is, or why such a difference would be necessary, but I'm a Java dev, so maybe I'm missing some grand DB-related concept here.

Could you guys help me out by any chance?
Thanks

Comment: why `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=n)` and not just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username=n`?

Comment: @zerkms err...idk. I think I see what you are getting at. I'll try that.

Comment: @zerkms Yep, Worked great! Set that comment as an Answer and I'll give you the big green checkmark of happiness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it helped you, but...

> why `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=n)` and not just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE username=n`?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the user name (or whatever the primary application index is) a `UNIQUE` index and then there is no need to test:  Just try to insert a new record.  If it already exists, handle the error.  If it succeeds, all is well.

It can (and should) all be one stored procedure.